# Is I797 Original document mandatory to travel to US for H1B visa holders?

Tags: usa, visa, paperwork, h1-visa

When someone travels to the US on H1B visa, is it mandatory to bring the I797 approval notice? Or is it okay to travel with just a photocopy of the I797 document?

Comment: cross-posting: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45450/is-i797-original-document-mandatory-to-travel-to-us-for-h1b-visa-holders

Comment: I was asked to post here when I first posted in travel. So posted the question here.

Comment: cross-posting is a bad idea, if your question is off-topic in travel, you should ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure where this question belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's mandatory**.

USCIS lags behind going all digital, they still rely on checking paper documents. Whether it will get check or not is bit random, but I've checked with a few people who travel on H1 or L1 very frequently and they say that about 50% of the time they are asked for I-797. As far as I know, USCIS accepts only the originals.